# Validate null while passing parameter to a function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I want to call a function that is accepts only non-Null parameter. However, the parameter that I am passing sometimes could be Null. I am new to Kotlin.

Here you can see in `myFirstFunction` parameter `customerName` expects a non-Null value. But `object1.object2?.object3?.customerName?` can be Null. So my question is how to use let function in this case?

```
function first () {
   if (State.Active == (status)) {
        secondFunction(
            object1.object2?.object3?.customerName?,
            "String to pass",
            accountId
        )
    } 
}
private fun secondFunction(customerName: String, message: String?, accountNumber: String) {

 // some logic goes here.

}
```

Comment: If the customerName is null, do you want to call `secondFunction` with empty `customerName` or don't want to call it at all?

Comment: @ArpitShukla probably no need to call.

Comment: Yeah, that's the assumption I took in my answer below. Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the customerName in a variable and then call `secondFunction` if name is not null.

```kotlin
function first () {
    if (State.Active == (status)) {
        val name = object1.object2?.object3?.customerName
        if(name != null) {
            secondFunction(
                name,
                "String to pass",
                accountId
            )
        }
    } 
}
```

Or you can also use the `let` extension function.

```kotlin
function first () {
    if (State.Active == (status)) {
        object1.object2?.object3?.customerName?.let { name ->
            secondFunction(
                name,
                "String to pass",
                accountId
            )
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that the second code block is equivalent to the first one, i.e. that also in that case the `secondFunction` is not called when the expression is null. You could also add the possibility to use `?:` (e.g. `?: ""`) to provide a non-null default value, in order to use the function in any case.